# jQuery not selecting Bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to add a listener to a button I created using Bootstrap.

```
<button type="button" id="buttonone" class="btn btn-default btn-lg good">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>' 
</button>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonone').on('click', function(){
        console.log("FIRED AWAY")
     })
  })
</script>
```

This doesn't `console.log` my message.

I also can't edit the CSS of my button using

```
.btn {

}
```

How come my bootstrap element doesn't respond to my listener or my CSS selector?

Comment: Is your JavaScript wrapped in a script block?

Comment: Are you creating the button with JavaScript? If so, you need to be sure that you do not attempt to invoke `.on('click', ...)` until _after_ you have already created the button. (or if that's not possible, look into using event delegation)

Answer (score 0):

So the only thing I can see is that you didn't put the js in a script block like so.

```
<script>
  $('#buttonone').on('click', function(){
      console.log("FIRED AWAY");
  });
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle showing both the click working and changing the style using css. Though ideally for non-trivial stuff you should separate your styles and js into their own files instead of using script/style blocks.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6h3nd37/1/